# Passing dataframe between 2 functions python

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

```
from varname import nameof
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

cwd = os.getcwd()

def output_to_csv(df):
    df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true")\
        .mode('overwrite')\
            .csv(cwd + '/output_files/' + nameof(df))
    return None


def main():
      spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
      ## other functions here ##
      output_to_csv(dataframe_abc)
      spark.stop()
```

So what I am trying to do is to dynamically name the output csv files from the function (pyspark) output_to_csv(). My desired output would be /output_files/dataframe_abc. The function works correctly in that it outputs the correct data from dataframe_abc. However, the outputted name for the folder containing the csv file from the spark output is "df" - from the original function. I'm new to Python and very new to PySpark. Can anyone give me a steer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you call `nameof` in `output_to_csv`, the variable name is in fact 'df' since it's local to the function and doesn't have a sense of the name of the variable that was passed in.

My suggestion would be to move the call to `nameof` into your `main` function, then pass that as an argument to the `output_to_csv` function:

```py
from varname import nameof
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

cwd = os.getcwd()

def output_to_csv(df, fname):
    df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true")\
        .mode('overwrite')\
            .csv(cwd + '/output_files/' + fname)
    return None


def main():
      spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
      ## other functions here ##
      output_to_csv(dataframe_abc, nameof(dataframe_abc))
      spark.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much @LiamFiddler! That solved that and makes sense to me